# xml with namespace not getting parsed in perl

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I have an xml with default namespace something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://127.0.0.1 GrammarXSD.xsd" version="01.00" xmlns="GrammarXSD.xsd">
    <DataModel>
        #rest of the xml
    </DataModel>
</start>
```

To parse this xml, I am trying to register the namespace using the following code:

```
my $file = "xml file location";
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom->documentElement());
$xpc->registerNs('ns',  'GrammarXSD.xsd');
my $b = $dom->findnodes('//ns:DataModel');
```

However this is not finding the DataModel nodes as expected.
The GrammarXSD.xsd file is in the same location as the xml.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You might find [the examples here](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/namespaces.html) useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the XPathContext object to search for nodes in a namespace-aware way:

```
my $data_models = $xpc->findnodes('//ns:DataModel', $dom);
```

BTW, don't use `my $b`, $b is a special variable used in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) and declaring it as lexical can cause bugs if `sort` is used later in the same scope.

Also, the namespace URI doesn't mean anything, it just identifies the namespace.